# Ajax request. Server returned null

Tags: php, ajax

JavaScript file. #form - html form. In var data - objects

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "... .php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(d) {
                ...

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Php file

```
$data =  json_decode($_POST['data']);
$dataJson = json_encode($data);
echo $dataJson;
```

Server returned Null. Why?

Comment: Have you check "data"(on javascript) variable ? (You can check it "console.log(data);")

Comment: [Object { name="name",  value="gsdg"}, Object { name="login",  value="g"}, Object { name="period",  value=""}]

Answer (score -1):

Why you decode `$_POST['data']`? All your form fields have prefix `data`?

Try this

```
$data = json_decode($_POST, true); // parse to array

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Comment: /Connection          Keep-Alive /
/Content-Length 180 /
/ Content-Type          text/html /
/ Date                  Thu, 24 Mar 2016 12:19:29 GMT /
/ Keep-Alive          timeout=10, max=98 /
 / Server                 Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) /

Comment: there no data in this code. You can open chrome console -> tab network, open your request to server, and make screen of data sended to server?

Comment: http://s10.postimg.org/ndifh7vc9/image.png    http://s9.postimg.org/nuqdqv6fz/image.png

Comment: On the last screen i see, that data not json-encoded, so In php file you dont need to make `json_decode`. simple do this: `echo json_encode($_POST)`